# 3-node Pacemaker setup shows 1 node 2 times, with the same name, one online and one offline

Tags: pacemaker, high-availability, corosync

So I've got: machine001, machine002, machine003.

machine001 has 2 resources, machine002 has 1 resource. Normally they don't go on the same host, unless machine002 goes in standby.

Recently, I saw machine002 appearing 2 times. 1 time online, 1 time offline.

Checking with `sudo crm_mon -R` showed they have different node ids.

I tried deleting the node id, but it refused. I tried deleting the node name, but was told there's an active node with that name.

I went in with `sudo crm configure edit` and it showed the configuration to be:

```
(111) machine001 \
    standby=off
(222) machine002 \
    standby=off
(333) machine003 \
    standby=off
(12345) machine002
other_settings... \
```

So, I remove the line     `(12345) machine002`, save and commit the CIB... and `machine002` completely disappears from the output of `crm_mon` and the output seems to constantly be trying to find it again...

Only way to get it back is to restart corosync and pacemaker on that node.

I'm at a loss for what is going on here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?